# Writing special characters to json file generates extra backslashes

Tags: c#, json, json.net, special-characters

Update: The backslash characters are also being parsed by stackoverflow. When writing/editing the question, it shows output as shown in the image(very different) given at the end but the actual question posted on the page is very different. Please see the image.

The problem, I am facing is that I get an extra backslash when writing to the file. I am generating image paths (available on the website) along with some text and writing in a json file. The generated string for the image path to be saved in file is as

```
ImagePath = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/"+YearcomboBox.Text+"/"+MonthcomboBox.Text+"/" + AddDashesFileName(Specialtitle) + ".jpg";
```

I need the output/the saved string in my file as

http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/abc-def-gh-2018.jpg

instead I get the path saved in the file with double backslashes

http:\/\/example.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/02\/abc-def-gh-2018.jpg

I have tried replacing the characters as

```
ImagePath = ImagePath.Replace("/",@"\\/");
```

which inserts two backslashes in the file.
Seondly I have to save some strings containing the special characters like

```
string ss="\r\n\r\nThe bla bla bla...";
```

when I write this string it saves the string with double backslashes as
\\r\\n\\r\\nThe bla bla bla...

instead I need the text in the format

\r\n\r\nThe bla bla bla...

The full code for the writing the file is as

```
string ss="\r\n\r\nThe bla bla bla..."; 
 ImagePath = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/"+YearcomboBox.Text+"/"+MonthcomboBox.Text+"/" + AddDashesFileName(Specialtitle) + ".jpg";
 ImagePath = ImagePath.Replace("/",@"\/");
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
 using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
 {
     writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    writer.WriteStartObject();
         writer.WritePropertyName("path");writer.WriteValue(ImagePath );
         writer.WritePropertyName("text");writer.WriteValue(ss);
         writer.WriteEndObject();
.
.
.the json entries which are working fine
}
 File.AppendAllText(@"e:\json\file3.json", sb.ToString());
```

Update:
[image]

Comment: For first part just use \`\\\` instead of `/`, but for second part, why would you even need to store new lines in JSON? JSON not a format for data visualization.

Comment: @SeM please refresh to see the update. I am using some wordpess plugin to generate and restore the backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to store invalid data into your JSON file.

The backslash (`\`) is a special character in the JSON format. It is used to escaped special characters within the file. If your string value contains the backslash itself you'll need to escape it (creating the `\\`). Placing a single backlash into your JSON file will escape whatever character comes next.

Now JSON converters generally do this for you, so you don't have to worry about it. That means that the value:

> http://specser.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/2/Special.jpg

should be formatted in your JSON file as:

> http:\\/\\/specser.com\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2018\\/2\\/Special.jpg

However, it is not clear to me why you are escaping the forward slashes, as these are perfectly valid to store unescaped in a JSON file.

---

As for your text value, the newline character (`\n`) is an special character. Meaning that if its based off user-input where the user itself writes a backslash followed by an *n* ("\n") most components will interpret it as text and not a special character (*ofcourse this greatly depends on whatever you are using*).

You can see the difference with a verbatim string:

```
string ss = "\r\n\r\nThe bla bla bla...";  // JSON: "\r\n\r\nThe bla bla bla..."
string ss = @"\r\n\r\nThe bla bla bla..."; // JSON: "\\r\\n\\r\\nThe bla bla bla..."
```

In the verbatim version the backslash and letter *n* are both stored as separate characters and not as a newline character.

---

To summarize, the example you show are exactly how JSON is supposed to work. You can checkout [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RVt6T8) that is based off your example code that it works fine.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your detailed answer. I want my json file to be formatted like http:\/\/specser.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/2\/Special.jpg. I am also doing the same as you told but issue is that it prints correct at the console but when writing to the file it inserts the extra backslash. It saves the string into file as http:\\/\/specser.com\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2018\\/2\\/Special.jpg.

Comment: @ImranKanjoo if you have a backslash in your string it _should_ escape it with an extra backslash, that's how the JSON format is defined. If you really want want to escape forward slashes, _which you should not have to escape_, in your JSON you can use `writer.WriteRawValue($"\"{ImagePath}\"");` to write the raw (unescaped) value.

Comment: As, I get, I have used    `ImagePath = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/"+YearcomboBox.Text+"/"+MonthcomboBox.Text+"/" + AddDashesFileName(Specialtitle) + ".jpg";
                     ImagePath = ImagePath.Replace("/",@"\/");.` using  writer.WriteRawValue, it has no change, its the same. When I see in messageBox or in console it gives correct as required but saves the same.

Comment: @ImranKanjoo checkout [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FntWhh), I've also run this locally and stored it into a file using `File.AppendAllText(@"c:\temp\text.txt", sb.ToString())`. Output is equal to output shown on console in fiddle. Are you using `System.IO.File.AppendAllText()` or are you using a custom one?